# Couchbase PHP Connect Hello World! on Mac

Tags: php, couchbase

I installed the Couchbase Server and its PHP SDK through `brew install libcouchbase` on Mac. The server admin console is running/working fine on http://127.0.0.1:8091/. I added a `hello.php` file with the below code in `/Library/WebServer/Documents/hello.php`.

```
<?php

$cb = @new Couchbase("http://127.0.0.1:8091/",'username','password');
if($cb->getResultCode() != COUCHBASE_SUCCESS){ 
    throw Exception('Cannot connect to couchbase!'); 
} else {
    echo "Hello World!";
}
```

When I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8091/hello.php`, I get an error saying `Not found.`. What is the problem?

Comment: You say "the below error", but there's nothing below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I go to http://127.0.0.1:8091/hello.php, I get the below error
>   Not found.. What is the problem?

You are going to the wrong port. Port 8091 is the Couchbase Server Console interface. It looks like you are trying to deploy your `hello.php` script using the Apache server shipped with OS X which uses the default http port (80). The script is also located in the wrong folder. I believe `/Library/WebServer/Documents/` is for static content only.

Given the problem you have ran into it make me suspect that you are trying to learn too many new things at once. You should try running the script outside of a Apache first and get it working there.

```
php hello.php
```

It is also worth pointing out that you are using the older 1.X version of the Couchbase PHP SDK, you will want to use the new [2.X version](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/php-2.0/php-intro.html).

Comment: Thanks Paddy for your answer. I have PHP/MySQL applications on `/Library/WebServer/Documents/` which are working well on port 80 without any problem. Shall I use the PHP/Couchbase application in the same path and port 80 (`http://localhost/hello.php`) as well?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've anonymized the code above, but be sure in place of where you have `'username'` you have the bucket name and similarly for the bucket password or empty string if no password.  Also, [check the docs](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/php-2.0/managing-connections.html) as the connect string you're using is not necessarily the preferred..

Note for debugging these kinds of things you can [set `LCB_LOGLEVEL` to a higher level as mentioned in the documentation](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/php-2.0/logging.html).  The way you set an envvar varies based on how you're deploying PHP, but you can easily just test it at the command line.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your answer. Can you give me a sample `hello world!` code that works on your computer?

Comment: Paddy's answer is correct, so I'm going to edit mine just to mention one other item.